# How to show distance in google map place search api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show the distance of the place from my location specified, in this map it's mexcio. Can someone help me how to show the distance. I'm new to google map api. I am attaching the [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/05Bizqh6FeHdR5jLtGWb?p=preview). Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (latLngA, latLngB);`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical. Where is your `from my location specified`? And where you want to show it?

Comment: Where do you want to show the distance?  In the infowindow? In the sidebar?  What distance do you want to show?  The straight line ("as the crow flies") distance, the driving distance, the walking distance?

Comment: I want to show the distance in the side bar and I want to show the line like driveway.

Comment: var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.786906,-122.410156); this is my current loation for this map